# What is the difference between an error and a warning in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello I would just like to know what is the difference between an error and a warning in mysql. I would like to know a very simple difference that I can simply understand since I am relatively new to this language and I am mostly a simpleton when it comes to this stuff. I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

An error in MySQL informs you that you actually did something wrong, describes the problem, and stops the process or query.

A warning will not stop anything, but is there to tell you that something happened that is not expected (or there may be a potential issue) and it's not critical enough to terminate.

Here's an example that illustrates the difference with an example using SQL imports: https://www.psce.com/blog/2013/04/17/diagnosing-problems-with-sql-imports/